# Where is `org-crypt` ? Need to install it with `use-package`

Tags: org-mode, use-package

I am trying to use `org-crypt` but cannot find where exactly is this package hosted.

I have:

```
(require 'package)
    (add-to-list 'package-archives '("melpa" .   "http://melpa.milkbox.net/packages/") t)
    (add-to-list 'package-archives '("org" . "http://orgmode.org/elpa/") t))
```

And then trying to use `use-package`:

```
(use-package org-crypt
:ensure t
:config
(org-crypt-use-before-save-magic)
(setq org-tags-exclude-from-inheritance (quote ("crypt")))
(setq org-crypt-key nil)
)
```

But this results in `package 'org-crypt-' unavailable`.
I cant find it in the package list too when I check with `list-packages`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`org-crypt.el` seems to be included within `org-mode` itself.

you can simply using it like:

```
(use-package org
  ...
  :config
  (require 'org-crypt)
  ...
  )
```